# How to use loops for repetitive code in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I know there are answers out there for this, but it is still confusing me as it is usually for more advanced tasks, and this is a very simple task.

I have 21 data frames that are in the format `data_1` `data_2` `data_3` etc. They all have the same headings, just with different values in the rows. I want to rename column 1 "ID" for all the data frames. I have been using:

```
names(data_1)[1] <- "ID"
names(data_2)[1] <- "ID" #etc
```

How can I make a loop to automatically cycle through all the data frames with that pattern?

I have another set of data frames named `df_1` `df_2` `df_3`. This df_1 has a common column (ID) that I would like to make an inner join with data_1, and repeat for data_2 and df_2 etc. I was using:

```
result_1 <- inner_join(data_1, df_1, by = "ID")
result_2 <- inner_join(data_2, df_2, by = "ID") #etc
```

How could I also loop this instead of repeating myself 21 times?

Comment: It is a good practice to have the data is a container ie list. eg `list1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "data_\\d+"))` and `list2 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df_\\d+'))` then you could loop over the two:`purrr::map(list1, list2, ~inner_join(setnames(.x, c('ID', names(.x)[-1])), .y, by = 'ID'))`

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to have the data as a container (i.e. a list). For example,

```
 list1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "data_\\d+"))
 list2 <- mget(ls(pattern = 'df_\\d+'))
```

then you could loop over the two:

```
purrr::map(list1, list2, ~inner_join(setnames(.x, c('ID',names(.x)[-1])), .y, by= 'ID'))
```

Comment: Sorry this did not work. Error in `purrr::map()`: 
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: data_1.
Caused by error in `pluck_raw()`:
! Index 1 must have length 1, not 36.